# Connection between Private GKE and Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy, kubernetes-cluster

I have a Private GKE Cluster with a public master endpoint, which has jobs that needs access Cloud SQL. I have a cloud SQL proxy DaemonSet receiving on 3307, which connects to actual DB on 3306.

My network doesn't have outbound internet, neither any firewalls rules added.
I get below error on my cloud SQL proxy. Any help on resolving this or guide on how to establish a connection between private GKE and Cloud SQL ?

> couldn't connect to "dbinstance": dial tcp publicip:3307: getsockopt: connection timed out

Comment: Have you followed the Google Kubernetes Cloud SQL documentation? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine

Comment: Yes, the approach followed is using Cloud Proxy Docker Image

Comment: Please follow [this group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/6lA0r6zRfeI) that recommends setting up [NAT gateway(s)](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-a-nat-gateway-with-kubernetes-engine) to achieve your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cloud SQL proxy uses database public IP to connect and as your cluster is private with no internet access from nodes I believe it is impossible to reach it like that. You could try using private IP for your SQL instance:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip

or conifguring the NAT gateway for your cluster:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-a-nat-gateway-with-kubernetes-engine

Comment: I was able to achieve this. To access SQL from private cluster, we can either enable Private IP for SQL or use NAT for VPC your cluster belongs to. Thanks @jkrol2